# How to delete all documents with same name without knowing where the document is - Firestore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a document with the name "Example123123". I don't know exactly in which collection/subcollection this document is.

How do I search within a collection and its subcollections to find this document and then delete it using Python?

Do I actually have to loop through my collections and subcollections to delete this document?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the full path of a document (including all of its collections and nested subcollections), and you aren't able to come up with a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) to find it, you will have to list and iterate collections deeply in order to build possible paths to find it and delete it.